# Parsing a list of lists and manipulating it in place

Tags: python, csv

So I have a list of lists that I need to parse through and manipulate the contents of. There are strings of numbers and words in the sublists, and **I want to change the numbers into integers**. I don't think it's relevant but I'll mention it just in case: my original data came from a CSV that I split on newlines, and then split again on commas.

What my code looks like:

```
def prep_data(data):
    list = data.split('\n') #Splits data on newline
    list = list[1:-1] #Gets rid of header and last row, which is an empty string

    prepped = []
    for x in list:
        prepped.append(x.split(','))

    for item in prepped: #Converts the item into an int if it is able to be converted
        for x in item:
            try:
                item[x] = int(item[x])
            except:
                pass
    return prepped
```

I tried to loop through every sublist in *prepped* and change the type of the values in them, but it doesn't seem like the loop does anything as the *prep_data* returns the same thing as it did before I implemented that for loop.

Comment: don't try to index into a list with the items that are in it (unless that's what you are actually trying to do...). When you loop over a list, it loops over it's **items directly** not the indices. IOW `item[x] = int(item[x])` will not work. This would have become obvious if you didn't use the horrible practice of silencing all errors with a bare `try:  ... except: pass`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm an amateur who's just learning to code, cut me a little slack. Why is doing that such 'horrible practice?'

Comment: Because it hides **all** errors, including ones that would have been actually useful for you to know. You only need trap the specific error that gets thrown when your input conversion  is invalid; all other errors should be reported "as usual", so you can debug the program if it is not working correctly.

Comment: Because it silences **all errors** not just the ones you expect. You were expecting a `ValueError` for when the `int(item[x])` fails, but you silenced a `TypeError` from trying to index into a list incorrectly with a string. You want to use `enumerate(item)` to let you iterate over the indices and items, to let you do something like `for i, x in enumerate(item): item[i] = do_something(x)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your function, because maybe I didn't understand your income data, but you could try something like the following because if you only pass, you could lose string or weird data:

```
def parse_data(raw_data):
    data_lines = raw_data.split('\n') #Splits data on newline
    data_rows_without_header = data_lines[1:-1] #Gets rid of header and last row, which is an empty string

    parsed_date = []
    for raw_row in data_rows_without_header:
        splited_row = raw_line.split(',')
        parsed_row = []
        for value in splited_row:
            try:
                parsed_row.append(int(value)
            except:
                print("The value '{}' is not castable".format(value))
                parsed_row.append(value) # if cast fails, add the string as it is
        parsed_date.append(parsed_row)
    return parsed_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what is wrong, you are thinking python is more generous with it's assignment than it actually is.

```
def prep_data(data):
list = data.split('\n') #Splits data on newline
list = list[1:-1] #Gets rid of header and last row, which is an empty string

prepped = []
for x in list:
    prepped.append(x.split(','))

for i in prepped: #Converts the item into an int if it is able to be converted
item = prepped[i]
    for x in item:
        try:
            item[x] = int(item[x])
        except:
            pass
prepped[i] = item
return prepped
```

I can't run this on the machine I'm on right now but it seems the problem is that "prepped" wasn't actually receiving any new assignments, you were just changing values in the sub array "item"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the indentation is off here and there. As it is quite vital in Python, you might want to fix your post.